# RDLC render to Excel change file default settings from code before download

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm using RDLC and export report to different formats using C#,
Now when I export the report to Excel file and open it the file have default settings,
Ex: Show gridlines : Not Checked
[image]

***Can I change these settings before file downloaded?*** 
I take a look at [Excel Device Information Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/excel-device-information-settings?view=sql-server-2017) but it seems have limited options 
Sample code I use

```
     var reportViewerExcel = new ReportViewer { ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local };
     reportViewerExcel.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
     reportViewerExcel.LocalReport.ReportPath = _reportPath;
     reportViewerExcel.LocalReport.Refresh();

     Warning[] warnings;
     string[] streamIds;
     string mimeType = string.Empty;
     string encoding = string.Empty;
     string extension = string.Empty;

     byte[] bytes = reportViewerExcel.LocalReport.Render("Excel",null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension,out streamIds, out warnings);

     HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",string.Format("attachment; filename={0}-{1}.xls", fileName, reportName));
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```